# Increment aaa to aab using Bash?

Tags: bash, loops

How can I increment characters similar to how numbers are done in bash?

Example; aaa -> zzz

```
for i in {aaa..zzz}; do
    echo -n $i;
done
```

Should result in:

```
aaa aab aac (...) zzx zzy zzz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf '%s ' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
```

If you really want to increment a character, you have to jump through some hoops:

First, you have to get the ordinal value of the character. This can be done with the [shell's weird leading-quote syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html):

```
$ printf -v ordA '%d' '"A'
$ echo "$ordA"
65
```

Next, you need to add one to that:

```
$ ordB=$(( 1 + ordA ))
$ echo "$ordB"
66
```

Then you need to format that value so it can be `printf`ed as a character:

```
$ printf -v fmtB '\\x%x' "$ordB"
$ echo "$fmtB"
\x42
```

Then, you finally `printf` it:

```
$ printf -v chrB "$fmtB"
$ echo "$chrB"
B
```

Whew. I'm sure some of that can be simplified, but those're the actual steps that need to be taken.

Comment: Simpler way to get the next character: `tr '\0-\376' '\1-\377' <<<"$char"`. Adjust as necessary per charset requirements. That doesn't solve the "increment a string" problem (i.e. aaz=>aba) which is slightly trickier.

Comment: I see what you did there. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}; do echo -n " $n"; done
```

Comment: How'd you end up finding the answer so quick after you posted the question?

Comment: Just some minor nitpicking here, but technically the `-e` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a comment to the answer by kojiro, if you really want to know how to increment an alphabetic string (as opposed to enumerating all possibilities), here's a solution (bash only, and it depends on the shell option `extglob`). It only works on strictly alphabetic lower-case strings, but it should be "obvious" how to extend it:

```
inc () { 
  local pfx=${1%%[^z]*(z)};
  [[ $pfx != $1 ]] && echo $pfx$(tr a-z b-za <<<${1:${#pfx}})
}
```

Example:

```
$ a=zyy; while echo $a; a=$(inc $a); do :; done
zyy
zyz
zza
zzb
zzc
zzd
zze
zzf
zzg
zzh
zzi
zzj
zzk
zzl
zzm
zzn
zzo
zzp
zzq
zzr
zzs
zzt
zzu
zzv
zzw
zzx
zzy
zzz
```

Comment: This works well, [I use it](https://github.com/la-ruby/run_id) to generate a unique (sequential) id for each invocation of a script I wrote.