# Prepend alphanumeric string to each file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have some video files inside some directories within a USB Stick plugged in in my TV.

Their name is something like:

```
1- Lists.mp4
10- Filter Function.mp4
11- List Comprehensions.mp4
12- Zip Function.mp4
13- Stacks.mp4
2- Accessing Items.mp4
20- Dictionary Comprehensions.mp4
```

Since my TV sort and play them in that wrong order I would like to rename those file in something like:

```
a 1- Lists.mp4
b 2- Accessing Items.mp4
c 10- Filter Function.mp4
d 11- List Comprehensions.mp4
e 12- Zip Function.mp4
f 13- Stacks.mp4
g 20- Dictionary Comprehensions.mp4
```

in a way that my TV can play them consecutively.

How can I rename recursively each file inside those directories in a way that I can prepend an alphanumeric value `a`, `b`, `c`, `...`, `aa`, `ab`, etc. in Bash?

---

Edit: That's different from [the question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412586/increment-aaa-to-aab-using-bash) because this is not a simply "increment characters" but this imply the use of zero padding and renaming files as well like pointed in the Gilles Quénot answer here below.

Comment: Better use zero padding: 001, 002, 003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
shopt -s globstar # enable recursion, used bellow with **
rename -n -d 's/\d+/sprintf "%.3d", $&/e' ./**/*.mp4
```

remove `-n` when happy with the output.

Output:

```
'001- Lists.mp4'
'002- Accessing Items.mp4'
'010- Filter Function.mp4'
'011- List Comprehensions.mp4'
'012- Zip Function.mp4'
'013- Stacks.mp4'
'020- Dictionary Comprehensions.mp4'
```

That way, player should play in the good order.

---

From comments, if you need to add the today date after the integer:

```
rename -n -d '
    BEGIN{ use POSIX; }
    s/\d+/sprintf("%.3d - %s", $&, POSIX::strftime("%F", localtime(time)))/e
' ./**/*.mp4
```

Comment: I think it is a great answer...

Comment: Could you do further evaluations on the right hand side if necessary?

Comment: What do you mean @g00se?

Comment: Well, let's say you wanted to put today's date *too* after that change. Would it work?

Comment: Sure! No problem, easy feasible.

Comment: Thanks, actually I got it with `rename -n "s/\d+/sprintf '%03d-%s', $&, \"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)\"/e" *.txt`

Comment: @GillesQuénot thanks! I can run this to do it recursively: `find . -depth -execdir rename 's/\d+/sprintf "%.3d", $&/e' '{}' \+`

Comment: @GillesQuénot please, edit your answer in order to include the recursive command above as well.